# AngularJs material form

Tags: angularjs-material

I have a very simple AngularJs material form. Just Name, email address and text with a very simple PHP code. Unfortunately, it's not working. I have used the same PHP code in live seerver without Angularjs Material. It worked. Now it iis not working anymore

Here are the codes

```
<form action="form.php" method="post">
        <md-input-container class="md-icon-float md-block">
          <label>Name</label>
          <input type="text" rows="5" name="name">
        </md-input-container>



        <md-input-container class="md-block">
          <input  type="email" placeholder="Email (required)" ng-required="true" name="from">
        </md-input-container>



        <md-input-container class="md-block">
                <label> message</label>
                <textarea rows="2" md-select-on-focus name="message"></textarea>
        </md-input-container>


        <md-button class="md-button" type="submit" name="submit">
                <md-icon class="material-icons">send</md-icon>
        </md-button>

</form>
```

The PHP Code

```
<?php

    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['from'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    $from = 'from the web';
    $to = 'the email address';


    $body = "From: $name\n E-Mail: $email\n Message:\n $message";

    if ($_POST['submit']){               
        if (mail ($to, $from, $body)) { 
        echo '<p>Worked</p>';
    } else { 
        echo '<p>Error</p>'; 
        } 
    } 
?>
```

I have also tried more straightforward way but didn't work. With this I just get a white screen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just found the Solution. The **md-button** is not submitting the information. If i replace the following part

```
<md-button class="md-button" type="submit" name="submit">
    <md-icon class="material-icons">send</md-icon>
</md-button>
```

with this

```
<input class="md-button" type="submit" name="submit"/>
```

It works.